# My Subaru's navigation system does not switch to night colors

Tags: subaru, navigation

I drive a 2017 Subaru WRX STI. I noticed, that my stock navigation system does not switch to night colors.

It does not matter wether I have my headlight turned on, off or on auto.

The day/night-cycle setting in the navigation control also works correctly, I can see my location lying in the dark at night - but nothing happens.

What is the issue, and how do I get my navigation to change its appearance?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Thanks, @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 - a question regarding your tag edit: As it seems this issue is not bound this specific model, even though its where I noticed it. The link in my answer mentions a Crosstrek for example. So wouldn't it be better to not add the model tag?

Comment: Tags are about the question, not the answer.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 this is true, and I'd surely have added the tag when posting the question, but I'd probably have removed it if it turned out it's not relevant for the answer. But I am fine with whatever helps more people :)

Comment: subaru like we know it, still the same in the outback 2019 :))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an undocumented navigation "feature"(?).

The night mode is disabled if the dashboard lighting is turned to the maximum. According to my mechanic this is the same for other models as well and might be fixed in an upcoming update.

You can find this solution in [this forum entry](http://www.subaruxvforum.com/forum/problems-maintenance-warranty/84393-maps-not-auto-changing-night-colors.html) as well.

To fix the problem, simply turn down your dimmer to not be on maximum level. In my case, the control is located to the left of the steering wheel:

[image]

If you want to keep your dashboard lighting to maximum level, you will need to manually switch the day color scheme in your navigation settings to darker colors, whenever required and hope for this to be changed in an update.